# SEO problems in the liferay blogs managing

Tags: seo, liferay, meta-tags

On my web site, google webmaster tools tells me that I have duplicate tags meta (`<meta description>`) in the blogs articles. This tag is linked to the field subscription in liferay administration and corresponds to the table layout in the database.

I would like to know if there is a simple solution to add a specific meta tag for each article.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that you are filling up Abstract field and tags for blog entries.

By default:

- Adding an abstract: The content will be ADDED (not overwritten) to meta description
- Adding tags: The tags will be ADDED (not overwritten) to meta keywords.

Blog URLs will have a little difference in those meta-tags between Pages and Blog entries.

Regards!